# What type of processor will I need to control a mobile front camera?

Tags: microprocessor, diy, imageprocessing

I have a mobile front camera [(like this one)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005DBTMXW). I want to build a wearable camera out of it [(like this one)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/wearable-pi-zero-camera/). However I want to make this from scratch and not have to resort to using a Raspberry Pi.

These are my requirements:

1. Take a photograph every fixed interval
2. Store it to a micro-SD card
3. Should be able to connect to PC via USB
4. (advanced/optional): Process images online and convert the raw file to a low resolution grey scale image.

So here are my questions:

1. What kind of processors will I need?
2. Is there an easier camera to work with? I want the size to be small.

Comment: Is this for video or just still images?

Comment: How much work do you *really* want to do for this when a rPi is the single-board-computer solution that can do it for you? Also, getting the iPhone camera's mating connector may be difficult and *will* require soldering a component with tiny pins.

Comment: Does "like this one" imply "I have *exactly* this camera model"? Or "I have a small camera with some flat cable"? The point is that though there are a few camera interface standards, it's not clear whether your camera follows one of these.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to get a raspberry pi and its camera module and play with it. To answer your question: You need an ARM processor with DSP capability. A cortex-M7 will do.

Comment: You mean cortex-**M**7? I think that, more important than DSP capabilities, the MCU requires a camera interface, because you definitely don't want to bit-bang this. And I actually wonder how this question is answerable, since we don't even know what kind of interface the camera specified by the OP uses.

Comment: Yes Cortex M7. I fixed the typo. For camera interface we need to use DMA and that is very hard to get it right. I worked for one month day and night on a STM32F camera module and could not get it right. DMA programming and all those low level interrupts are though. But I appreciate the op enthusiasm. He should give the ARM a try.

Comment: What I've used is sensor -> FPGA-> DSP. You get a lot of data with a camera. 1M sensor @ 25fps outputs 600mbps. It is quite involved to make it work on a processor, but the smallest FPGAs can handle that.

Comment: yes he can use ARM processor on FPGA.